# Does SQL Server Management Studio has an "Action Output" window?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm used to work with MySQL Workbench which has an Action Output panel that displays a summary of the communication between the active MySQL connection in MySQL Workbench and the MySQL server.

[image: MySQL Workbench Action Output]

Is there a panel in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that recreates this outcome?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.4 (2017).

Comment: yes it has something similar, for query output, it's called Results, and for actions, called Messages, and for analyzer, called Live Query Statistics, and also Query Execution Plan

Comment: And also you can fire up the SQL Server Profiler from the Tools menu and watch all communication being processed by SQL Server across all databases and clients.

Comment: Thanks @iSR5 but Results or Messages don't replicate the outcome we see in Action Output of Workbench. Action workbench let's you see all the queries you have run, the time, and results. It's like having a record of everything you have run so you could reuse it...

Comment: Results = Results Grid, Messages = Message (in Action Output).. timing is shown at the bottom right of the screen (the yellow bar) this will show the query time. other details will be under Query Live Statistics and Query Execution Plan. Sorry, but SQL Server is a bit different in view, naming and techniques. So, there is no ONE window for everything as of my knowledge.

Comment: I understand, I was wondering if they have something like this tool that was so useful for me. Thanks

Comment: nothing built in. you might find an addin with somewhat similar functionality though

Comment: That's what I thought. Any addin that you could recommend?